# FFMPEG C++, Best practise / pattern for encoding a live feed

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I have got working code that captures from /dev/videox and encodes a h264 file just fine, that is like this:

1. grab frame from camera
2. possibly do a rgb-yuv tango
3. encode with ffmpeg lib
4. repeat

Single thread.
Now here is my thinking, if the time taken for 2 and 3 sums up to be larger than 1/25th of a second I will miss a frame from the camera. 
Not unfeasable right? 
A spike in load on the target system and frame(s) are dropped.
So I am thinking I should thread this and put in a buffer between capture and encoding.
Now the question(s) is.

1. Is my line of thinking correct?
2. Is my solution a variable one?
3. How much of a problem is it really, would it fail anyway, am I about to create a solution for which there is no problem.

Insights ? :)

Thanks

Comment: Splitting the job of capturing and encoding in different threads is a good thought. Another could be to speed up the bottleneck of encoding. How big are your frames and did you compile with high optimization and use of SIMD instructions?

Comment: Thanks, no, no SIMD or high optimization yet, i am still in the development phase (of a homebuild surv. system), just want to get it right from the beginning.
Thanks for your input :).